# Where do you put small snippets of CSS codes for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I know that most CSS codes go under app/assets/stylesheets, but I have some snippets of CSS codes that are specific to only certain pages. For now, I just have these small CSS codes included in the view files, but I feel like there's ought to be a better way of handling this.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails convention is to put these in controller specific CSS files:

> For example, if a ProjectsController is generated, there will be a new
>   file at app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee and another at
>   app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss. You should put any
>   JavaScript or CSS unique to a controller inside their respective asset
>   files, as these files can then be loaded just for these controllers
>   with lines such as <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
>   or <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>.

Putting the CSS inside the views isn't a good idea as you lose features (fingerprinting, auto minification) that the asset management in Rails provides.

Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline